# Find diagonal elements of the inverse for large matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, linear-regression

Consider the set of invertible matrices $\{\mathbf{C}_{n}\}_{n=1}^N$ defined as
$$\mathbf{C}_n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \mathbf{0}^\top_{k_1} & \mathbf{0}^\top_{k_2} &\cdots & \mathbf{0}^\top_{k_n} \\ 
\mathbf{0}_{k_1} & \mathbf{X}^\top_{1}\mathbf{X}_{1} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_1 & \mathbf{X}^\top_{1}\mathbf{X}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{X}^\top_{1}\mathbf{X}_{n} \\
\mathbf{0}_{k_2} & \mathbf{X}^\top_{2}\mathbf{X}_{1} & \mathbf{X}^\top_{2}\mathbf{X}_{2} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_2 &\cdots & \mathbf{X}^\top_{2}\mathbf{X}_{n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{0}_{k_n} & \mathbf{X}^\top_{n}\mathbf{X}_{1} & \mathbf{X}^\top_{n}\mathbf{X}_{2}  &\cdots & \mathbf{X}^\top_{n}\mathbf{X}_{n} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_n\end{bmatrix}, \quad n=1, \ldots, N,$$

where $\mathbf{0}_{k_1}$ denotes a vector of $k_1$ zeros, $\mathbf{X}_{n}\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k_n}$, $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_{n}\in \mathbb{R}^{k_n \times k_n}$ are singular but semidefinite positive matrices and we assume that $\mathbf{X}^\top_{n}\mathbf{X}_{n} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_n$ is invertible for each $n=1, \ldots, N$.

> $\textbf{Objective}$: Find the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{C}_n^{-1}$, the inverse of $\mathbf{C}_n$ (assume that, for large $n$, the size of the matrix $\mathbf{C}_n$ prevents to compute the entire inverse due to numerical issues).

I managed to compute iteratively the set of matrices
$$\mathbf{M}_n = \mathbf{B}_n \mathbf{C}_n^{-1} \mathbf{B}_{n}^\top, 
\qquad \text{with} \quad \mathbf{B}_n = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0}_{m} & \mathbf{X}_{1} & \mathbf{X}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{X}_{n} \end{bmatrix}$$
for each $n=1, \ldots, N$, which we assume that are matrices much smaller than $\mathbf{C}_n$.

With them, I was able to compute the elements of the bottom right block of the inverse (and hence, its diagonal elements). Indeed, denoting as $\mathbf{F}_{n}$ the bottom right block of the inverse of $\mathbf{C}_n$, using the block matrix inverse formula we have that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{F}_n = (\mathbf{X}_n^\top \mathbf{X}_n + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_n - \mathbf{X}_n^\top \mathbf{B}_{n-1}\mathbf{C}^{-1}_{n-1}\mathbf{B}^\top_{n-1} \mathbf{X}_{n})^{-1} = (\mathbf{X}_n^\top \mathbf{X}_n + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_n - \mathbf{X}_n^\top \mathbf{M}_{n-1}\mathbf{X}_{n})^{-1}.
\end{equation*}
In this computation, only matrices up to size $\max\{m, k_{n}\}$ have been involved, and thus we assume that they can be calculated precisely. I tried to compute similarly the other blocks, but I was not able to find a pattern, and bigger matrices were involved in the computation. Is there a way to find these diagonal elements precisely?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By any chance, can we assume that each $\mathbf \Gamma_j$ is invertible?

Comment: No, they are not invertible.

Comment: That's too bad... are the $\mathbf \Gamma_j$ at least positive semidefinite?

Comment: Yes, they are positive semidefinite

Comment: In that case, my approach might be salvageable using the [pseudoinverse-based formula given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Pseudoinverse_with_positive_semidefinite_matrices).

Comment: It also might be possible to compute $\Bbb C_n$ using $\Bbb C_{n-1}$ in some way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it's helpful (e.g. perhaps it can be modified to work using pseudoinverses), here's an approach that works if $\Gamma_j$ for $j = 1,\dots,n$ are invertible.

First of all, note that for the block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 0_k^T\\0_k & B}
$$
$A$ is invertible iff $B$ is invertible with inverse given by
$$
A^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&0_k^T\\0_k&B^{-1}}.
$$
So, we can safely restrict our attention to the submatrix
$$
\mathbf{D}_n = \begin{bmatrix}  
 \mathbf{X}^\top_{1}\mathbf{X}_{1} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_1 & \mathbf{X}^\top_{1}\mathbf{X}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{X}^\top_{1}\mathbf{X}_{n} \\
\mathbf{X}^\top_{2}\mathbf{X}_{1} & \mathbf{X}^\top_{2}\mathbf{X}_{2} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_2 &\cdots & \mathbf{X}^\top_{2}\mathbf{X}_{n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{X}^\top_{n}\mathbf{X}_{1} & \mathbf{X}^\top_{n}\mathbf{X}_{2}  &\cdots & \mathbf{X}^\top_{n}\mathbf{X}_{n} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_n\end{bmatrix}, \quad n=1, \ldots, N.
$$
It is notable that we can write this matrix in the form $\mathbf D_n = \mathbf G_n + \mathbf \Xi_n^T\mathbf \Xi_n$, where
$$
\mathbf G_n = \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf \Gamma_1,\dots,\mathbf \Gamma_n), \quad \mathbf \Xi_n = \pmatrix{\mathbf X_1 & \cdots & \mathbf X_n}.
$$
$\mathbf G_n$ is block-diagonal, so its inverse is easily computed as
$$
\mathbf G_n^{-1} = \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf \Gamma_1^{-1},\dots,\mathbf \Gamma_n^{-1}). 
$$
From there, we could apply the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) to get
$$
\mathbf D_n^{-1} =\mathbf G_n^{-1} - \overbrace{\mathbf G_n^{-1} \mathbf \Xi^T}^{\mathbf U_n^T}\overbrace{(I + \mathbf \Xi_n \mathbf G_n^{-1}\mathbf \Xi_n^T)^{-1}}^{\mathbf Y_n}\overbrace{\mathbf \Xi_n \mathbf G_n^{-1}}^{\mathbf U_n}
$$
The term $\mathbf U_n^T \mathbf Y_n \mathbf U_n^T$ requires only the computation of an $m \times m$ matrix. Note that we can rewrite $\mathbf U_n, \mathbf Y_n$ as follows.
$$
\mathbf Y_n = \left(\mathbf I_m + \mathbf \Xi \mathbf G_n^{-1}\mathbf \Xi^T\right)^{-1} = \left(\mathbf I_m + \sum_{j=1}^m \mathbf X_j \mathbf \Gamma_j^{-1} \mathbf X_j^T\right)^{-1}.
$$
Note that $\mathbf Y_n$ can itself be updated from $\mathbf Y_{n-1}$ using the Woodbury identity, which is especially useful if $k_n$ is small compared to $m$. We have
$$
\mathbf U_n = [\mathbf X_1 \mathbf \Gamma_1^{-1} \ \ \cdots \ \ \mathbf X_n \mathbf \Gamma_n^{-1}].
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\mathbf U_n^T \mathbf Y_n \mathbf U_n^T = 
\left[\mathbf \Gamma_i^{-T} \mathbf X_i^T\left(\mathbf I_m + \sum_{j=1}^m \mathbf X_j \mathbf \Gamma_j^{-1} \mathbf X_j^T\right)^{-1}\mathbf X_j\mathbf \Gamma_j^{-1}\right]_{i,j = 1}^n.
$$

---

We can make this work for positive semidefinite $\mathbf \Gamma_j$ as follows. Consider the following definitions:

- For each $j$, let the matrix $L_j$ be such that $L_jL_j^T = \mathbf \Gamma_j$. In particular, I will take $L_j$ to be the [positive semidefinite square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Positive_semidefinite_matrices) root of $\mathbf \Gamma_j$ so that $L_j$ is symmetric.
- $X = \operatorname{diag}(L_1,\dots,L_n)$.
- $Y = \mathbf \Xi_n^T$
- $Z = (I - XX^+)Y$
- $E = I - X^+Y (I - Z^+Z) F^{-1} (X^+Y)^\mathrm T$
- $F = I + (I - Z^+Z) Y^\mathrm T (XX^\mathrm T)^+ Y (I - Z^+Z)$

We can then compute
$$
\mathbf C_n^{-1} = \mathbf C_n^+ = 
(XX^\mathrm T + YY^\mathrm T)^+
= (ZZ^\mathrm T)^+ + (I - YZ^+)^\mathrm T X^{+\mathrm T} E X^+ (I - YZ^+).
$$

Some simplifications:

- $X^+ = \operatorname{diag}(L_1^+,\dots,L_n^+)$
- $(XX^T)^+ = \mathbf G_n^+ = (X^+)^2 = \operatorname{diag}([L_1^+]^2,\dots,[L_n^+]^2)$

Comment: Very nice answer! How can this be adapted to the case in which $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_j$ are not invertible but semidefinite positive?

Comment: @user326159 See my latest edit

Comment: The problem that I see is that a large pseudo-inverse $(ZZ^T)^+$ must be computed...

Comment: That’s a fair point… I try to think of a way to get around that if I have the chance later

Comment: Notably, the product $Z^+Z$ can be directly computed from $Z$ without the intermediate step of a pseudoinverse computation (using a QR decomposition of $Z$), that could help significantly

Comment: I do not see how this makes the problem more tractable...

Comment: Computing a large QR decomposition of a $k \times m$ is much easier than computing a $k \times k$ pseudoinverse (where $k = \sum_i k_i$), especially if $k \gg m$.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible to store a matrix of the dimensions of $\mathbf{C}_n$, one possibility is to use a randomized estimator for the diagonal in conjunction with a linear-system solver.

In particular, note that for a matrix $\mathbf{A}$, and random vector $\mathbf{v}$ with iid entries equal to  $\pm 1$ each with probability $1/2$,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{v}\circ (\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v})] = \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{A}).
\end{equation*}
Here we use $\circ$ to denote the [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) which just multiplies elements entry-wise.

If you set $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{C}_n$, then you can compute $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}$ by solving the linear system $\mathbf{C}_n \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}$.
This could be done by a Krylov subspace method which would allow you to avoid even forming $\mathbf{C}_n$ itself. I suspect you can take advantage of the structure of your matrix to speed up product with $\vec{C}_n$.
If you have some other solver of choice, you could of course use that instead.

For a single vector $\mathbf{v}$, the variance of $\mathbf{v}\circ (\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v})$ may be big. But you can just average a bunch of iid copies to reduce the variance.
There are more clever approaches based on this general idea as well.

Here are some references:

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.10684.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.03268.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. However, I need very precise estimates for my application, so this approach is not suitable. I am wondering if this elements can be computed using a closed form.